# I making adb console and I blocked

Tags: cmd.exe, adb

I wanna input 'check Specific Third-Party App version' to in my console option like App ver : 1.2.345
and I using this cmd prompt on next

```
:Appver
cd %localappdata%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
mkdir "App ver"

set datetime=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set datetime=%datetime: =0%

cls

@echo off
echo org.mozilla.firefox

for /f %%1 IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package org.mozilla.firefox | grep 'versionName='"') do set Appver=%%1

echo App ver        %Appver%

pause

cd App ver

echo App ver        %Appver% >>"%datetime%_App ver.txt"

start "" "%localappdata%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\App ver"`

for /f %%A IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package org.mozilla.firefox | grep 'versionName='"') do set Appver=%%A
echo Appver : %Appver%
```

then, displayed on next

```
Result : Appver : versionName=1.2.345
```

I wish : `Appver : 1.2.345`

how to solve this?
I tried set str

```
set str=%str:versionName==%
```

but, displayed nothing

```
Appver :
```

Comment: Thank you. who edit my dirty Explain...

Answer (score 0):

In your `For /F` use `tokens^=1*delims^=^=  %%1` and define your variable `set AppVer=%%2`

```
for /f tokensˆ=1*delimsˆ=ˆ= %%1 IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package org.mozilla.firefox | grep 'versionName='"') do set Appver=%%~2

...

for /f tokensˆ=1*delimsˆ=ˆ= %%A IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package org.mozilla.firefox | grep 'versionName='"') do set Appver=%%~B
```

**Obs.:** You also have the option to use [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) or [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) instead of grab, these are native to Windows.